# How do I revoke Gatekeeper permission to launch from an unsigned app?

Tags: macos, applications, security, gatekeeper

[Gatekeeper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gatekeeper_(macOS)) is a feature of macOS that prevents unsigned applications from being launched. It can be disabled host-wide in System Preferences, or you can keep the protection in place and exempt a single application by right-clicking and choosing "open" which prompts a dialogue with the option to "launch anyway" (rather than simply double-clicking, which prompts a dialogue with no option to launch, only dismiss).

Forever after, that application will launch without issue. Gatekeeper has presumably whitelisted it. How can I revoke this exemption and remove the application from the whitelist after once approving it?

[Apple's support document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491) suggests consulting the manpage for `spctl` for more information. Going from there, I've tried `spctl --disable` <*path to app*>, `spctl --remove` <*path to app*>, and `spctl --add --label disable` <*path to app*>; `spctl --disable` --label disable, but the app still launches successfully when double-clicked in Finder.

[OSXdaily](http://osxdaily.com/2015/07/15/add-remove-gatekeeper-app-command-line-mac-os-x/) suggests that `spctl --remove` <*path to app*> should have done the trick, and indeed after running that command, the application no longer shows up under the whitelist of exempted applications with `spctl --list | grep` <*app name*>. But the app still launches. How do I get this revocation to stick?

Comment: Is the app still quarantined, or did its quarantine attribute get removed? Without that, the gatekeeper policy will not even be checked. You can see if it's still there with `ls -ld@ /path/to/application.app` and see if "com.apple.quarantine" is listed below it.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: yes, that command shows the info "com.apple.quarantine  61". Should that mean it should not launch?

Comment: @ziggurism That means it should be applying the policy. What does `spctl --assess -vv /path/to/application.app` show?

Comment: @GordonDavisson: <path to app>: rejected
source=no usable signature

While experimenting, I did a `spctl --disable` before I tried `spctl --remove`. Could that be the reason why Gatekeeper is ignoring my revocation?

Comment: Weird; my understanding was that if it had the com.apple.quarantine xattr and `spctl --assess` rejected it, you shouldn't be able to open it (without some sort of override). So I'm not sure what's going on in your case.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Does this work for you?

Comment: I am reproducing exactly the same issue on Sierra, except that for me the response to `spctl --assess -vv /path/to/application.app` is:

/path/to/application.app: rejected (resource envelope is obsolete (version 1 signature))

Comment: This question has been answered. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256625/how-to-set-restore-the-com-apple-quarantine-attribute