# Allowing many (unverified) apps to run

Tags: macos, terminal, verify

I downloaded a package that contains a bunch of executables. When I try to run any of them from the terminal, I get the "cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified" thing, so I cannot run it. I know I can go in the Security settings to allow this one app to run. But this requires doing it one by one. Is there something I can do from the terminal to allow all apps in a directory (say) to run?

Comment: I'm crossposting from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73872164/allowing-many-unverified-apps-to-run. It's the first time I post in this forum so I wasn't sure what's the proper place to ask this.

Comment: Have you tried removing the quarantine extended attribute?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Can you tell me how I can do that? Sorry if it's a naive question.

Comment: See [How does macOS identify the signing status of an app downloaded from the Internet?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321473/how-does-macos-identify-the-signing-status-of-an-app-downloaded-from-the-interne). If you still have questions, post a comment. Otherwise, I will assume your question has been answered and flag to close as a duplicate question.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks, that link has the answer to my question! Feel free to close as duplicate.

Comment: Turns out I can mark as duplicate myself.