# How can I give a file the com.apple.quarantine attribute on mac

Tags: macos, extended-attributes

I have used xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Users/username/Desktop/app_name.app to remove the attribute but I don't know how to give the attribute again. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

The attribute is not just a flag: it contains a sequence of meaningful bytes. (The `-w` option of `xattr` requires attribute data to write to the file.)

Here's an example of the contents from a file in my Downloads folder:

```
0083;5b4da585;Safari;D1E5E911-DF67-4DCA-8CD4-2AE126B44CEF
```

Unless you can recreate the correct data manually, or already have the old metadata for that file in a backup (in which case you might as well just restore the whole file), introducing the wrong quarantine data may cause unexpected problems.

[This question appears to be similar, and describes how to set the correct metadata.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256625/how-to-set-restore-the-com-apple-quarantine-attribute)

It is somewhat odd to re-introduce quarantine, as that suggests you no longer trust the file.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by replacing the `-d` (delete) flag with `-w` (write). So:

`xattr -w com.apple.quarantine /Users/username/Desktop/app_name.app`

A handy tip if you are unsure about a command is to look up the **man page** for it.

If you type `man xattr` it will give you a list of available options for that command with explanations. (to navigate the manual use the arrow keys and press the `q` key to quit.)