# Why am I able to run my own app without code signing?

Tags: macos, code-signing, gatekeeper

I have a little open-source Qt app I wrote and then compiled on my Mac. I ran `macdeployqt` and copied it to my /Applications folder, and it runs without complaint.

Ultimately I plan to sign this app with an Apple developer certificate and upload it to GitHub as a binary release. But my question is: why am I able to run this app locally from /Applications without macOS complaining, even though I haven't yet signed it? Is this because of some special attribute or permission that's been set on the app's binary by the system's compiler? If so, how can I view this attribute for myself?

Comment: Do you have Apple developer account which has been added to Xcode -> Preferences -> Account?

Comment: Nope. And also:

% codesign -dv --verbose=4 /Applications/towerofhanoi.app
/Applications/towerofhanoi.app: code object is not signed at all

Comment: What's your setting of System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> General -> Allow apps downloaded from ?

Comment: Allow apps downloaded from: "App Store and identified developers"

Comment: I have checked Xcode and in Signing & Capabilities Signing Certificate dropdown list by has an option "Sign to Run Locally". Is this option set in your app ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## `com.apple.quarantine`

The locally built application does not have the `quarantine` attribute set. Without this extended file attribute, the application bypasses macOS's Gatekeeper and verification steps.

The `quarantine` attribute is set when the application is downloaded or copied onto the computer.

Try uploading a compressed copy of your application onto a [web server](https://miln.eu/beyond), then downloading the file. After downloading and expanding the application, macOS will now apply Gatekeeper and verify the contents.

See [How to set (restore) the com.apple.quarantine attribute?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256625)

Comment: No need to upload the binary to anywhere else. I often test whether signing was successful by just creating an ad-hoc HTTP file server in the binary's directory, e.g. using Python: `python3 -m http.server`. Now just download the file from http://localhost:8000.

Comment: (Of course you could instead also just set the quarantine extended attribute on the file, but where would be the fun?)