# macOS Monterey version 12.3 how to rollback security override of an executable?

Tags: security

I have downloaded an unix executable file. It didn't open earlier showing this reason "Apple can’t check app for malicious software". But later when I opened it once, it was added as a security exception (here is a formal steps of what happened actually [link to apple support](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchleab3a043/mac).

Is there anyway I can change it back to the previous state? I want macOS to complain about this particular file like it did before.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what this executable is; what it does; and why you want the OS to warn you?

Comment: Download the file again.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Actually did this thing after deleting and then redownloading it. It somehow remembers but I wonder how...

Comment: @benwiggy That's a good question. It's basically the `cloudfared` executable that we need for tunnel management. It's *open-source*. So my hyper reaction ha reduced a lot after knowing this piece of information. 
I want the OS to warn me thinking "let's make the machine as safe as it is recommended by the Apple itself - preventing malware and other stuff"

Comment: You need to re-apply the quarantine flag, as here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256625/how-to-set-restore-the-com-apple-quarantine-attribute