# Reverse Quarantine Application

Tags: terminal, gatekeeper

I used the following Terminal command to Quarantine a test app I have been making which worked fine

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Untitled.app
```

Is there a way to bring it back to its original state ( reverse the quarantine ) so when it runs I get the usual message.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate of this question: [How to set (restore) the com.apple.quarantine attribute?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/256625/406217)

This is the summary of the top answer (currently):

> You can copy an existing com.apple.quarantine attribute of an arbitrary file to a proxy file and then apply it to arbitrary other files. If you open certain file types (e.g. .txt files) the quarantine attribute will be ignored though.

> Example:

> xattr -p com.apple.quarantine /Users/user/dnscrypt-osxclient-1.0.12.dmg  quarantine.attr

> xattr -w com.apple.quarantine "`cat quarantine.attr`" test.command

> This will apply the data gathered from the .dmg to the .command file - including download date and download app of the original dmg file. The original download date/app of the .command won't be restored though.

> Source: [Using xattr to set the Mac OSX quarantine property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591485/using-xattr-to-set-the-mac-osx-quarantine-property)

For more details, go check out the original answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/256646/406217) (which I have quoted)